# azure-notificationhubs IOS Bad request

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I send notifications to mobile platforms via Azure portal. There is no problem on Windows and Android platforms, but I can not send 4 days notice to the IOS platform and I get this error[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I have tested sending test messages to my mobile platform on Azure portal, I have configured Notification Services for Windows (WNS), then I could send test message successfully to my UWP app. While sending a message to Apple platform, then I could encounter the same error as follows:

[image]

Since the error is too broad, then I leverage Notification Hub sdk to send a message to Apple platform as follows:

```
hub.SendAppleNativeNotification(
"{ \"aps\": { \"alert\": \"This is my alert message for iOS!\"}}");
```

**Error**

[image]

In summary, please make sure you have correctly configured the Notification Services for Apple (APNS) and the notification payload format is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Azure notification hub uses 1 year of apple certification. Since this time has passed, I am getting a bad request error, I wish it was somewhere, certifications have been renewed and the problem is solved